# I want to stop all the audios playing in the webbrowser otherthan my site using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to stop other audios playing when mysites audio is playing....I have designed an website embeding an audio player when user start the player I want to stop all other audios playing by other sites. Is this possible

Q) IS it possible to onkeyup event will not work for tab

Comment: don't think your script will be allowed to access other tabs on the browser, that will be a big issue in security

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: Suppose it were possible, and one of those other sites used it...

Comment: Access the microphone with the getUserMedia() API, analyse the audio and then play a noise cancelling audio track to counter unwanted audios. How hard could that be :)

Answer (score 1):

No. That is entirely impossible.

In general, you cannot interfere with what other sites are doing in a web browser.

There are some circumstances where you can, but this requires a specific relationship to the other site (such as "It opened your site in a frame") and the cooperation of the other site (e.g. to exchange messages with `postMessage`). Your description of the problem meets neither of those requirements.

Comment: Can we make onkeyevent not work for tab functionality

Answer (score -2):

No, you can not control the functions of the other sites and browsers from your site. Your visitors land on your site as the clients and the question that you're asking is a serverside functionality.

Comment: Not my downvote but this line is completely wrong: *and the question that you're asking is a serverside functionality.*

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Agreed !